# Новичок в Vim как закрыть все окна, если закрыто окно редактора?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Я довольно недавно начал использовать ВИМ, перешел из VsCode так как в arch есть проблема с записью в файлах...
У меня ужа настроен NERDTree, но я никак не могу закрыть окно терминала, как мне это сделать?

```
autocmd BufEnter * if tabpagenr('$') == 1 && winnr('$') == 1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() | quit | endif

botright :terminal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, чтоб выполнить vim ex-команду, когда активно окно терминала, нужно перед ней ввести <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> и потом <kbd>:</kbd>.

Чтоб в принципе выйти из vim закрыв все окна нужно дать команду `:qa` в ex режиме. Но это работает, только если нет несохраненных изменений в буферах редактирования. Иначе нужно либо сохранить все буфера, либо принудительно закрыть буфера с потерей несохраненных изменений. Это делается командой `:qa!` (восклицательный знак означает "закрыть принудительно").

Когда запущен терминал, то есть дополнительная сложность - он может выполнять команду и его закрытие извне в любом случае требует принудительное закрытие. Лучше всего закрыть терминал выполнив команду выхода в самом терминале. В зависимости от того, какой у вас shell, это или команда `exit` или символ конца файла (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> в linux/mac или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> в Windows). И после этого можно закрыть vim обычной командой, т.е. `:qa` или `:qa!`.

Если же нужно закрыть принудительно все окна, когда терминал в фокусе, то нужно использовать все вместе: <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>:qa!</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.